# Lots of sounds coming from my car. Can you help?

Tags: brakes, suspension, steering

I'd really appreciate your advice on an issue I am having with my 2003 Lexus ES300. It currently has 180k miles on it, and was a family hand me down, so I know a little about it's history if that matters. Although there's not much to report on that end. Never been in an accident and normal maintenance. No major parts have had to be replaced (other than brakes, oil changes, transmission flush, etc) so any of the following possible issues would involve the original parts ( in other words, they're old so anything could go).

The issue has something to do with the steering components, suspension, or brake system. The issue started with hearing a high pitched metalic grinding or scraping sound that corresponds with the wheel rotation so it's a rhythmic sound. I can only hear it at slow speeds and when I'm quiet areas (it's not a loud). There's no feeling of this through the steering wheel.

Then I started hearing a clunking sound when braking. The funny thing is, I can only hear it when I'm braking as I'm pulling into  my garage. I'm sure it happens at other times, but for some reason I only hear it then. It might help to mention my driveway has a steep pitch with my garage at top on level ground. I'm not sure if going up the hill then leveling off has anything to do with parts moving/shifting and then hearing the sound when braking.

Then recently my anti lock brakes have started engaging any time I am coming to a stop. It doesn't happen when just slowing down, only when at very low speeds while coming to a stop. At first it happened just once during my drive, but over the last week it has increased to happening every time I come to a stop.

Then just the other day, I started hearing a squeaking when making a turn (anything less than a 90 degree turn).

I just had new pads and rotors put on, and there was no mention of anything obviously broken or failing. Although I don't know how closely they were looking.

I don't know if all of this is coming from one issue, or if I have a few issues going on. After internet research, I have a list of things it could be:

Steering fluid low
Steering belt
Steering rack
Steering pump
Tie rod
Ball joint 
Wheel bearing
CV joint/shaft
Control arm
Control arm bushing
Sway bar
Sway bar bushing
Upper strut bushing
Upper strut mount

This is quite a long list of potentials, so I'm hoping you guys could help narrow it down for me based off all of my symptoms.

Thank you very much for your help and for sharing your expertise with all of us novices!!

-Laura

Comment: A good way to narrow it down is to drive askew from the sidewalk, so that every wheel touches down one at a time. So you should be able to localize eventual problems with the suspension by listening to the noise.

Comment: At 180K miles it's almost certain that some of the suspension components are worn.  Things like bushings, tie rod ends, wheel bearings, shocks, etc.  They can all make such noises.

Comment: Martin- great suggestion! I will definitely try this!

Comment: JWH- I know I have a long list of potential problems, and I know I'm asking a lot for you guys to diagnose over the Internet. I appreciate any advice that could save me even a few dollars, or at least prepare me for what the repairs will cost:)

Comment: To all- From what I've read, I'm leaning toward wheel bearings or control arm bushing.  Two questions though:

Comment: . First, if it is the wheel bearing or control arm bushing, would either of those cause the ABS brakes to engage? I'm just wondering if that's related or if it's a separate issue (faulty sensor)  Second, if I crawl under the car and take a good look, would an issue with the wheel bearing, bushing, etc be obvious

Comment: Also, I know someone that has a code reader (not a professional one but one that's pretty good apparently), would this kind of issue show a code? Or is it too "mechanical" for the computer to pick up? Thank you for your help!! I really really appreciate it!!!

Comment: The codereader is useless here (unless your Check-Engine-Light lights up, but that would be another issue). This sounds like a pure mechanical issue. Did you had success locating the origin of the noise?